# How to handle asynchronous socket receiving in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

I'm currently using a thread to handle Connect and Send calls asynchronously. This is all working fine, but now I want to make receiving asynchronous too. How should I receive data without pausing the whole queue while waiting for data? The only solution I can think of right now is a second thread.

Comment: framework? boost? Qt? raw Windows API? linux? Tell more please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look into [non-blocking sockets](http://www.kegel.com/dkftpbench/nonblocking.html) and polling APIs like [`select(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)/[`poll(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)/[`epoll(4)`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll)/[`kqueue(2)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2).

Specifically in C++, look into [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Comment: Non-blocking sockets should be enough if you handle the case that recv() does not read any data (which is easy). Using select() or something similar has its advantages but also drawbacks. It's up to you to decide what suits your needs better.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're doing, non-blocking I/O with [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) may be the answer.

[Take a look at this tutorial](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select_tut).