# Start functions in a c++ application with a command over tcp

Tags: c#, c++, tcp

I have an application, in c++, streaming data to another application, in C#, via a TCP socket that is always open.

What I would like to do is start and stop functions in the c++ app, by sending a command from the c# app.

Is this possible over TCP? I have only ever sent streaming data, a nudge in the right direction for sending commands and triggering functions would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could receive the "switch feature on" command on C++ side, just like You receive on C# side. Than for example implement State design pattern, where the feature is on/off. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017234/how-to-handle-asynchronous-socket-receiving-in-c

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I checked the link, but am confused. Do i need to listen constantly in a thread on the c++ side, and 'start function' if the state is changed?

Comment: Not necessarily, but if You want user input meanwhile receiving the "switch feature on", than it's advisable. Usually C# side is multi threaded as well, using AcceptTcpClientAsync() and SendAsync() on TcpClient's socket

Comment: besides user input it's also a question, and You could edit Your post, if the C++ application can connect to multiple C# clients or not. If yes, than each client must be handled paralelly.

Comment: just one client. So, to be clear, I should look at using a State design pattern(which I need to find out more about!) and a listen thread ?

Comment: If it's 1-1 connection, than You can use synchronous connection, synchronous listening. Check the state design pattern anyway. (if there is no user interaction at the sides)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. As long as 1-1 connection is established, You can implement C# side as

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
...
client.Client.Send(someActivisationCommandAsByteArray);
// or client.Client.SendAsync if user interaction is requered.
```

on the C++ side implement State design pattern, and switch between states when the `someActivisationCommandAsByteArray` comes. This can be implemented as doing normal work, but every now and then check if the tcp socket received value (check [How to handle asynchronous socket receiving in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017234/how-to-handle-asynchronous-socket-receiving-in-c)). If it received the command, call the `setCurrent` method of the pattern.